# Why my timer1 not working?

Tags: c, xc8, pic16f877a

My purpose is to measure phase angle between 2 square wave as below(yellow represent voltage ZCD and blue represent current ZCD passing through ACS712 hall effect current sensor)

[image]

Below is my circuit connection in proteus
[image]

I connect one of the voltage source(yellow square wave) to CCP1 for rising edge detection.
Below are my interrupt command. What I Trying to do here is to start counting the processing the calculation after detected 3 rising edge after power on(value may not be stale upon power on so ignore the first 3 data) as shown in the interrupt command. PORT RB6 and RB7 is to detect the input from current and voltage zero cross detection circuit. After passing 3 rising edge, the code will try to compute if voltage leading or lagging current on each CCP1 trigger. In the while loop I run the timer when voltage!=current to get the count and it should finalize the count and stop counting when voltage==curent.With the input value of TMR1=65526,prescalar=4 and crystal frequency=4Mhz, I should have a tick of 25000 in one second but the TimerCount/tick i obtained is very small so I not sure where I did wrongly.

The interrupt command

[image]

[image]

Various register value

[image]

My global variable declaration

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the while loop when you are counting the number of times that the Timer1 Interrupt flag is set, each time through the loop you need to reload Timer1 with its starting value otherwise it will rollover and count from zero each time.

The time taken for certain code instructions needs to be taken into account if accuracy is important, for example the time required to reload Timer1 after each rollover. Consider writing this section of code in assembly language which is more commonly used for time critical code where the time taken for the execution of each instruction can be more easily determined.

EDIT

To avoid having to reload Timer1 after every rollover, you could use Timer2 in conjunction with the PR2 register instead of Timer1. How this works is that Timer2 counts up from zero until it matches the value that has been pre-loaded into the PR2 register. When a match occurs Timer2 rolls over back to zero and the Timer2 interrupt flag is set.

Comment: Do you mean putting the command line TMR1=65526 in the while loop in ISR?

Comment: Essentially yes, but, for accuracy, the value of 65526 will need to be adjusted upwards if you want to stick with a 40us time between Timer1 rollovers. This is because it takes time (overhead) to reload Timer1. How much adjustment of that value is required would be more easily determined in an assembly language routine.

Answer (score 0):

> processing the calculation after detected 3 rising edge after power on (value may not be stale upon power on so ignore the first 3 data)

OK, so why are you counting yourself? This is what CCP is for. Connect this signal to `T1CKI`, use CCP1 in compare mode, and load CCPR1 with "3". When you get an interrupt, you know to stop waiting.

You have a lot of code in your ISR, including a polling loop on `TMR1IF`. This is a recipe for disaster. Interrupt servicing should be very short. If you absolutely need a polling loop, move it to your main routine; but in this case a polling loop doesn't seem like a great idea. You already have an ISR - why not use it to pay attention when you get `TMR1IF`?

Your method to get the phase shift (`TimerCount`, etc.) seems strange to me. I would expect that when you get an interrupt from a rising edge of the leading component, it resets the timer; and then when you get an interrupt from a rising edge of the lagging component, that triggers a capture event, after which you pull CCPR. CCPR contains the timer value after capture. Why is there no reference to CCPR in your code?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out other alternative, just learned pic16f877A not long ago. Have not aware of this function. I will try it out.